# How to serialize/deserialize case classes to/from Json in Play 2.1

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize some case classes to/from Json... and I've troubles when dealing with case classes with just one field (I'm using Play 2.1):

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class MyType(type: String)

object MyType {

  implicit val myTypeJsonWrite = new Writes[MyType] {
    def writes(type: MyType): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "type" -> MyType.type
      )
    }
  }

  implicit val myTypeJsonRead = (
    (__ \ 'type).read[String]
  )(MyType.apply _)
}
```

The code above always generates the following error message:

```
[error] /home/j3d/Projects/test/app/models/MyType.scala:34: overloaded method value read with alternatives:
[error]   (t: String)play.api.libs.json.Reads[String] <and>
[error]   (implicit r: play.api.libs.json.Reads[String])play.api.libs.json.Reads[String]
[error]  cannot be applied to (String => models.MyType)
[error]     (__ \ 'method).read[String]
[error]                        ^
```

I know... a case class that contains just a string does not make much sense... but I need to serialize/deserialize a case class very similar to the one I described above that comes from an external library.

Any idea? Am I missing something? Any help would be really appreciated... I'm getting crazy :-( Thanks.

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20130414/1435971 for example to convert json to scala case class

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Json combinators doesn't work for single field case class in Play 2.1 (it should be possible in 2.2)

Pascal (writer of this API) has explained this situation here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!starred/play-framework/hGrveOkbJ6U

There are some workarounds which works, like this one:

```
case class MyType(value: String)
val myTypeRead = (__ \ 'value).read[String].map(v => MyType(v)) // covariant map
```

ps: `type` is a keyword in Scala, it can't be used as parameter name (but I assume it's just for this example)

edit: This workaround is not yet required with play 2.3.X. The macro works fine.

Comment: You can capture `type` in a JSON serialization case class by wrapping the field name in backticks.  I can't figure out how to show you that in markdown because the backticks are the code blocks :)

Comment: this should work: `\`type\`` — just escape them with a backslash, like this: `\`\\`type\\`\``

Comment: I'm using Play 2.3 (Scala) and I also needed to workaournd this limitation. I don't think it's fixed yet.

Comment: I've just tested with Play 2.3.8 and it works fine with sigle-field case class. I also encourage you to check this library (https://github.com/jto/validation) which has more features around Json/Xml/Form validation.

Comment: @JulienLafont Could you post a gist of your working 2.3.8 example? Like Felipe, I too get errors in 2.3.8 without the workaround.

Comment: Thanks!  I missed that you had said the *macro* works in 2.3.8.  The long-form syntax still doesn't work with a single arg, but the macro is cleaner anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is that (as far as I can tell) the Play 2.1 framework only handles tuples starting from `Tuple2`. In the examples it's used like this:

```
case class CaseClass(key1: String, key2: String)
object CaseClass {
  implicit val caseClassFormat = {
    val jsonDescription =
      (__ \ "key1").format[String] and (__ \ "key2").format[String]

    jsonDescription(CaseClass.apply _, unlift(CaseClass.unapply))
  }
}
```

And then to use it

```
val caseClassJson = Json.toJson(CaseClass("value1", "value2"))

println(caseClassJson)
println(Json.fromJson[CaseClass](caseClassJson))
```

In your case you can not use the `and` method (you only have one value) and thus get no access to that nice `apply` function of `FunctionalBuilder#CanBuildX` (where X is 1 to 22).

In order to supply something similar you can create an implicit class that provides a `build` method with a similar signature as that nice `apply` method

```
implicit class FormatBuilder[M[_], A](o: M[A]) {
  def build[B](f1: A => B, f2: B => A)(implicit fu: InvariantFunctor[M]) =
    fu.inmap[A, B](o, f1, f2)
}
```

Now you can adjust your case class like this

```
case class MyType(tpe: String)

object MyType {
  implicit val myTypeFormat =
    ((__ \ "type").format[String]) build (MyType.apply _, unlift(MyType.unapply))
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
val myTypeJson = Json.toJson(MyType("bar"))

println(myTypeJson)
println(Json.fromJson[MyType](myTypeJson))
```

Comment: The solution given by EECOLOR boils down to using 'inmap', which transforms a `Format[A]` to a `Format[B]`. It is tersely documented [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonCombinators). You can also use `inmap` directly, but EECOLOR's solution cleanly extends the JSON combinators.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply add a unused field to the case class. put a decent comment or use a field name that is self explanatory.

```
//f2 is unused field for de/serialization convenience due to limitation in play

case class SingleField(f1: String, f2: Option[String]) 
object SingleField {
   implicit val readSingleField : Reads[SingleField] = (
        (__ \ "f1").read[String] and 
           (__ \ "f2").readNullable[String])(SingleField.apply _)  
}
```