# Play2.1 Json.validate compiler error "type mismatch; found : *** required: play.api.libs.json.Reads[?]"

Tags: json, playframework-2.0

I have searched for a solution to this problem to no avail. I am validating a json request. See below for implementation. I am implementing Facebook's OAuth2 client. As recommended by Facebook's documentation, after receiving the access token for a user, you should "perform an automated check to confirm that the token belongs [to] the person that your app is expecting it to belong to." I am thus making a separate request, validating that the details are as expected. The following code produces the compiler error: "type mismatch; found : Inspection.type required: play.api.libs.json.Reads[?]". Can someone help me through this? I saw a similar post :

[type mismatch error when creating Reads for Play 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800051/type-mismatch-error-when-creating-reads-for-play-2-1)

That, however, did not help me come to a solution.

```
def inspectAccessToken(json : JsObject) : Future[JsObject] = {
  val accessToken = (json \ "access-token").as[String]

  // defines a custom reads to be used
  def equalReads[T](v: T)(implicit r: Reads[T]): Reads[T] = Reads.filter(ValidationError("validate.error.unexpected.value", v))( _ == v )
  def equalDateReads(v : DateTime)(implicit r : Reads[DateTime]) : Reads[DateTime] = Reads.filter(ValidationError("validate.error.unexpected.value", v))( _.toDateMidnight == v.toDateMidnight )
  def getDateTime(implicit r : Reads[Int]) : Reads[DateTime] = r.map { d => new DateTime().plusSeconds(d) }


  case class Inspection
  (
    app_id : Int,
    application : String,
    expires_at : DateTime,
    is_valid : Boolean,
    user_id : Int
    )

  implicit val customReads : Reads[Inspection] = (
    (__ \ "app_id").read(equalReads(clientId.toInt)) ~
      (__ \ "application").read( equalReads("Application")) ~
      (__ \ "expires_at").read( getDateTime keepAnd (equalDateReads((json \ "expiry-date").as[DateTime]))) ~
      (__ \ "is_valid").read( equalReads(true)) ~
      (__ \ "user_id").read[Int]
    )(Inspection.apply _)

  WS.url(
    inspectTokenUrl + "?inputToken=" + accessToken +
    "&access_token=" + appToken
    ).get map { secR =>
      val jsonR = secR.json

      jsonR.validate(Inspection)
      .................
      Addl. Code






}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonR.validate(Inspection)
```

should be just

```
jsonR.validate()
```

, as you have defined the implicit Reads object that will be used for parsing.