# Scala JSON Reads/Writes

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm starting to play with Scala and while doing some examples from play framework page, I've found problem which I can't resolve. I'm pretty new in Scala so I please to be forgiving.

Why this one compiles without errors:

```
case class Location(lat: Double, long: Double)

implicit val locationReads: Reads[Location] = (
    (JsPath \ "lat").read[Double] and
        (JsPath \ "long").read[Double]
    )(Location.apply _)
```

but this one won't compile:

```
case class Location(lat: Double)

implicit val locationReads: Reads[Location] = (
    (JsPath \ "lat").read[Double]
    )(Location.apply _)
```

and displaying error:

> overloaded method value read with alternatives:
>   [error]   (t: Double)play.api.libs.json.Reads[Double] 
>   [error]   (implicit r: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Double])play.api.libs.json.Reads[Double]
>   [error]  cannot be applied to (Double => biz.JsonProtocol.Location)
>   [error]                 (JsPath \ "lat").read[Double]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out there are some limitations when using JSON combinators with single-field case classes in play versions <= 2.1 (it has been marked as [solved](http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/918-play-21-json-issues#ticket-918-4) already). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042205/how-to-serialize-deserialize-case-classes-to-from-json-in-play-2-1) question for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can't have a biz.JsonProtocol.Location with only a latitude...that's why your exemplar with lat AND long works but just lat won't compile